# GAWK Print string to STDOUT with -i inplace option

Tags: awk

I would like to run a GNU AWK script that is editing files in-place (e.g. with the `-i inplace` option) and have it print the filenames it is working on to STDOUT. Is there a way to do this? The following just adds the filename as the first line in the modified file, rather than printing the filename on the command line:

```
BEGINFILE {
  print FILENAME
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to print tracing information like that to stdout instead of stderr?

Comment: `BEGINFILE { print FILENAME > "/dev/stderr" }`

Comment: @kvantour Could you move your comment to an answer? I'd like to accept it, manipulating the `inplace` extension works but redirecting to stderr seems more elegant

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't consider printing to `stderr` rather than `stdout`, that seems like a great solution. Thanks for your comments on the other answer to this question!

Comment: @EdMorton It was your idea, feel free to add this as an answer.

Comment: kvantour Id rather not as @oguzismail has provided the answer to the question that was asked and I don't want to distract from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround; drop `-i inplace` from the command line (not an obligatory though, see `-e`/`-f`) and place following at the very beginning of your script. Before starting to process a file's content, this will disable `inplace` temporarily and print `FILENAME`. Then `inplace`'s `BEGINFILE` rule will enable itself again.

```
BEGINFILE {
    if (inplace::filename != "") {
        inplace::end(inplace::filename, inplace::suffix)
        inplace::filename = ""
    }
    print FILENAME
}

@include "inplace"
```

See [how `inplace` is implemented](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace) for a better understanding.

Comment: Nice but I'd have gone with `awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{ inplace::end(inplace::filename,inplace::suffix); print FILENAME; inplace::begin(inplace::filename,inplace::suffix) } ... '`

Comment: @EdMorton I wouldn't want awk to call `inplace::begin` twice, is there any advantage of your version over mine other than aesthetic reasons? See what `begin` does [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/extension/inplace.c)

Comment: @oguzismail readability. The example of Ed Morton is understandable without knowing the internals. Your statement looks a bit more cryptic.

Comment: @kvantour I said **other than aesthetics**. See the internals of `inplace::begin` at the link I added to my comment

Comment: @oguzismail it's just for clarity. I don't see any reason not to do it that way - did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: Yes @Ed , begin does many things like creating a new temp file, modifying it to make it look like the original input file (I mean perms etc), that's too much work, and doing it twice while you can avoid is not a good practice in my book

Comment: For my tastes doing that one extra time per file is not a big deal and worth the small performance hit for the benefit of clarity, simplicity, and robustness in the users code. I strongly dislike that with your approach the user can't use `-i inplace` and has to be careful about where they place the `@include "inplace"` relative to the BEGINFILE in their script.

Comment: That's a matter of taste then. Let your comment lie here for future viewers, or add it to the answer. Wrt your edit, and on the contrary I strongly dislike specifying libraries on the command line

Comment: Idk, but there is a shorter version in revision history, `end` with empty args doesn't change the behavior

Comment: To be clear - I'm fine with using `include "inplace"` and would definitely recommend it for any script you're going to save and re-use (but `-i inplace` is absolutely fine for throwaway scripts or small awk scripts as part of a shell script, for example), I just want all my "include"s at the top of the script and not have to carefully place them within the script.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for the answer! I asked kvantour to move their solution using a redirect to `stderr` into an answer so I could accept it, that approach seems simpler and more elegant. But I'm very glad to learn how extensions in AWK work from your answer, and how to print a filename using the `inplace` extension (I upvoted your answer).